# How to bypass JavaScript timer with Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, countdown, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to bypass a 60 second countdown timer using Tampermonkey. This is the JavaScript from the page source:

```
var sec = 60, sInt, s = 'Please wait %s before downloading.';
function countDown() {
    var f = $('#download');
    if (sec < 0) {
        d.html('<div style="margin: 10px auto" class="center"><form action="" method="post">\
        <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="REMOVED">\
        <div id="REMOVED" style="width:450px;margin:5px auto"></div> \
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Get download link" name="download"> \
        </form></div>');
        hcaptcha.render('REMOVED', {
            'sitekey': 'REMOVED'
        });
        clearInterval(sInt);
        return;
    }
        d.html(s.replace('%s', sec +' second'+ (sec != 1 ? 's' : '')));
        sec--;
}
$(function() {
    sInt = setInterval(countDown, 1150);
});
```

(a few items were substituted with 'REMOVE' but should not have effect I don't think)

So far I have tried the following but didn't work:

```
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
     var sec = 0;  
})();
```

Any suggestions to make this work?
I think any of these two methods would work, but not sure how to do it:

1. either change the var sec to 0, or
2. change the countDown milliseconds from 1150 to 0.

So can either of those be done? If so, how can you do it?

Comment: You'd need to change `sec` to `-1`. You'd also have to do that after the page script has run. If you run before, the script will overwrite your changes as the first thing it does is set those variables.

Comment: If `sec` is declared in global scope, you can simply use `sec = -1` or `window.sec = -1` (not `var sec = -1`, which creates a new variable with the same name). If `sec` isn't in the global scope, you'll need to find out what _is_ available and find a creative way to exploit that. A good starting point is `console.log(window)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The likely problem is the declaration of `sec` is in a different scope to the `sec` declared in the website's script. As a result you're not setting the value on the same `sec`.

## Solution

### Mutating `sec`

You'll need to find if it's possible to make manipulations in the same scope as where `sec` is declared by the website. This is only really possible if the website author has declared `sec` in the global scope. If they've declared it in the global scope doing `window.sec = -1;` should work. If not, then you may need to manipulate the timer.

### Manipulating timers

Manipulating timers can be a big task. Take a look at [sinonjs/fake-timers](https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers/blob/master/src/fake-timers-src.js) for what complexity could be involved. I don't think such a complex solution is necessary for what you want here, so let's just manipulate the timer by hijacking it. The below will hijack `setInterval` and cause intervals to run (as close as possible to) immediately. Caution should be taken when using this because if there is an interval that is never cleared and it performs memory intensive tasks then it could crash your browser/computer.

```
const hijackedInterval = window.setInterval;

window.setInterval = (fn) => {
  return hijackedInterval(fn, 0);
};
```

Below is a demo. There are two immediately invoked function expressions to demonstrate different scopes. The first performs the hijacking of `setInterval`. The second is a counter which increments every second. Once 10 seconds has passed `DONE!` should be logged to the console. However as we've hijacked `setInterval`, the log occurs immediately.

```js
(() => {
  const hijackedInterval = window.setInterval;

  window.setInterval = (fn) => {
    return hijackedInterval(fn, 0);
  };
})();


(() => {
  let counter = 0;
  let intervalId;
  
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (counter === 10) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      console.log('DONE!');
      return;
    } else {
      counter++;
    }
  }, 1000);
})();
```